# Iterate over edges at a node

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm trying to clip edges that have irregular values in my graph, the actual values associated with these edges are stored outside `networkx`. I plan to iterate over all the nodes in my graph to do this kind of pruning (100,000 elements).

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_node(3)
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3)])
edges=G.get_edges_from_node(2) #(1,2),(2,3)
```

I can't quite seem to find the function for this.

Comment: What do you mean by irregular values?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso Its something specific to my problem, in my case the edges hold values (outside of `networkx`). So, if the values of edges, leading to a node look like `[1,2,3,999]` then I would prune the last connection.

Comment: Can you state a sample input and a sample output?  Perhaps you're simply looking for `G.edges(2)`, but it's not clear.

Comment: So you're saying you are working with a weighted graph? check this example out: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/examples/drawing/weighted_graph.html

Answer (score 2):

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_node(1)
G.add_node(2)
G.add_node(3)
G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(2,3)])
```

You can iterate over all the nodes in the following manner:

```
for n in G.node.items():
    print(n)

(1, {})
(2, {})
(3, {})
```

You can also add your values, which are outside the graph, as an edge attribute and simply iterate over the edges

```
G2=nx.Graph()
G2.add_node(1)
G2.add_node(2)
G2.add_node(3)
G2.add_edges_from([(1,2, {'value': 1}),(2,3, {'value': 2})])

for edge in G2.edges(data=True):
    print(edge)

(1, 2, {'value': 1})
(2, 3, {'value': 2})
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes here looking for what the question title says ...

Here are some ways you can loop over edges at a node

1. `nx.Graph.edges`

   ```
   G.edges([1, 2, 5])  # edges incident on nodes 1, 2 and 5
   G.edges(0)          # edges incident on node 0
   ```
2. `nx.Graph.adj`

   ```
   G.adj[0]            # neighbors adjacent to node 0
   ```
3. subscript notation

   ```
   G[0]                # neighbors adjacent to node 0
   ```